# Cause of "possibly undefined method"

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, factory-pattern

I'm working through a Space Invaders example from a book (ActionScript 3.0 Design Patterns, O'Reilly) and I've gotten things pretty well figured out except now I'm seeing

```
internal/space-invaders/trunk/ship/ShipFactory.as, Line 11  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method drawShip.
internal/space-invaders/trunk/ship/ShipFactory.as, Line 12  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method setPosition.
internal/space-invaders/trunk/ship/ShipFactory.as, Line 14  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method initShip.
```

and I haven't the foggiest idea why.  Scoping?  Bad inheritance?  Package visibility?  Have I misunderstood AS3's polymorphism rules?  Here (in order) are the base class, child class, and factory class:

Base class in `Ship.as`:

```
package ship {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    class Ship extends Sprite {

        function setPosition(x:int, y:int):void {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        function drawShip( ):void { }

        function initShip( ):void { }

    }

}
```

Child class in `HumanShip.as`:

```
package ship {
    import weapon.HumanWeapon;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    class HumanShip extends Ship {

        private var weapon:HumanWeapon;

        override function drawShip( ):void {
            graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
            graphics.drawRect(-5, -15, 10, 10);
            graphics.drawRect(-12, -5, 24, 10);
            graphics.drawRect(-20, 5, 40, 10);
            graphics.endFill();
        }

        override function initShip( ):void {
            weapon = new HumanWeapon();
            this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this.moveShip);
            this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.fire);
        }

        protected function moveShip(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace('MOVE');
            this.x = event.stageX;
            event.updateAfterEvent();
        }

        protected function fire(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace('FIRE');
            weapon.fire(HumanWeapon.MISSILE, this.stage, this.x, this.y - 25);
            event.updateAfterEvent();
        }

    }

}
```

Factory class in `ShipFactory.as`:

```
package ship {
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class ShipFactory {

        public static const HUMAN:uint = 0;
        public static const ALIEN:uint = 1;

        public function produce(type:uint, target:Stage, x:int, y:int):void {
            var ship:Ship = this.createShip(type);
            ship.drawShip();
            ship.setPosition(x, y);
            target.addChild(ship);
            ship.initShip();
        }

        private function createShip(type:uint):Ship {
            switch (type) {
                case HUMAN: return new HumanShip();
                case ALIEN: return new AlienShip();
                default:
                    throw new Error('Invalid ship type in ShipFactory::createShip()');
                    return null;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that jumps out at me is that the methods in your base "Ship" class don't have access modifiers on them. Try explicitly making them public! I'm not sure what AS3 defaults to if an access modifier is not specified, they may be being treated as protected.

Comment: It's my understanding that the default modifier is `internal`, which is what I had them set to previously.  I'll give another go with `public` and see if that changes the behavior at all.

Comment: That's a negative.  Adding explicit access modifiers to the `Ship` methods (and to the overrides in `HumanShip`) does nothing.

Comment: But thanks to Adobe's version of IntelliSense, I was lead to play around with variable names.  Evidently AS3 doesn't like it when you name temporaries in class methods the same as the package in which the class appears.  Accepting anyway - thanks for the help!